# facebook share dialog place

Tags: facebook, web, share, facebook-social-plugins

I'm working on a site regarding restaurants and I would like to have a Facebook share dialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) for each restaurant so that people can check-in there.

I searched everywhere and I couldn't find how to open a share dialog that has the place added already.

I want users to be able to check-in very easy, with the place already added, without needing to log in via Facebook and that's the problem, because I don't have and I don't want a token so that I can post directly via Graph API with /me/post.

Do you know if this is possible and if yes, how?

Comment: No, that is not possible, the Share dialog does not take that as a parameter. Perhaps you should go for an Open Graph story instead – there exists a pre-defined `restaurant.visited` action already. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph#action-type

Comment: I tried it but it requests a token for this action and it doesn't give the client the opportunity to customize the message or to tag friends. I'm looking for something that the users are used with. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the Share dialog to publish Open Graph stories as well, and that does not require an access token.